Padding zeros to ensure uniform length
I am trying to append an array of zeros with shape (6,) to list containing array of same length but instead of appending array of zeros , integer zero is appended.
def padded_list(data,column):
    """Returns the list of equal length paddes the list with length less than max length"""

    max_len = max(len(val) for sublist in data[column] for val in sublist)
    equal_lst = []

    
    for innerlist in data[column]:
        padded_lst = []
        for sublist in innerlist:
            #sub = [np.array(arr) for innerList in data[column] for sublist in innerList for arr in sublist]
            if len(sublist) == max_len:
                padded_lst.append(sublist[:max_len])
            else:
                difference = max_len - len(sublist)
                #sub = [np.array(arr) for innerList in data[column] for sublist in innerList for arr in sublist]
                #padding = sub + [np.zeros(6,) for _ in range(difference)]
                padding = [np.zeros_like(sublist) for _ in range(difference))]  # Create arrays of zeros
                sublist = np.concatenate([sublist] + padding)
                padded_lst.append(sublist)
        equal_lst.append(padded_lst)        
    return equal_lst

I am using above code to perform the same
The data on which i want to perform the padding is of the following
type
0      [[[-0.17601687, -0.014907939, 0.031924307, -0....
1      [[[-0.02781348, 0.010587102, 0.14018357, -0.10...

What is the mistake in the code?
expected output
[[[array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])]]]

Instead getting output as
[[[array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]), 0]]]


could you provide a minimal working example? In particular, it is missing the input.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

better create minimal working code with example data directly in code - so we could simply copy and run it.

sublist = np.concatenate([sublist] + padding) repeated concatenate like this is bad use of numpy.  Lists grow easily with append, arrays don't.  But this is small enough code that you can add a bunch of print lines to keep track of what's happening.

copy-n-paste of the function does not work.  Also give one or ore sample frames, such as one that works and one that demonstrates the problem(s).
